# How to loop through json data and implement on flatpickr

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Firstly, I know that this question has been asked but I've tried most if not all of the solutions that were offered and cannot get it to work correctly.

I'm using flatpickr with my Symfony 3 project, and I need to be able to disable certain dates, based on holidays booked. When a certain person is selected from a drop down, the system queries the database to find out if they are on holiday at any point and, if so, returns those dates as a 'from' and 'to'. The result is then JSON encoded and returned via the Ajax response.

This is an example response from the Ajax call:

```
[{"from":"2017-06-05","to":"2017-06-09"},{"from":"2017-06-27","to":"2017-06-28"}]
```

And flatpickr requires a set of dates to disable, like so:

```
{
    disable: [
        {
            from: "2017-04-01",
            to: "2017-06-01"
        },
        {
            from: "2017-09-01",
            to: "2017-12-01"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I used the following jQuery to try and get the desired result:

```
$.each(response, function(i, dateitem){
        console.log(dateitem.from + " - " + dateitem.to);
});
```

For testing purposes, but nothing shows. `response` being the return result from the database in the Controller.

Can anyone help me to convert this data into the correct format for use with Flatpickr as I'm struggling quite a lot.

Comment: `console.log` is showing from and to dates correctly from your json.

Comment: No, it's not - that's just the raw response. If you look at my console log you'll see I am only printing the from date, a hyphen, and the to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did it the long way round, where you state each date in sequence to be disabled.

I used `DatePeriod()` to get all the dates between the from and to, and then tacked on the end date again (as `DatePeriod()` doesn't do this) as follows:

```
foreach ($holidays as $row) {
    $start_date = new \DateTime($row->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d'));
    $end_date = new \DateTime($row->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d'));
    $date_range = new \DatePeriod($start_date, new \DateInterval('P1D'), $end_date);
    foreach($date_range as $date){
        $date_array[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    // Add the end date as this is not included in the date period.
    $date_array[] = $row->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

I fed the ajax a json encoded result, and then on the ajax success:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(response);

var optional_config = {
    enableTime : true,
    disable: parsed
};
```

and that did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

This definitely worked for me.  I am not showing you the server code because you are using PHP and I am using C#.  If you want my server code, please request.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index800</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/2.6.3/flatpickr.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/2.6.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //MAKE SURE TO click on Ok button to fill jsonDateRanges
            var jsonDateRanges;
            $("#btn").click(function (ev) {
                var AjaxDataReceive = { organizationId: $("#ddOrganization").val() };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/Index800",
                    data: AjaxDataReceive,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#output").val(JSON.stringify(response.AjaxDataSend));
                        jsonDateRanges = response.AjaxDataSend;
                        $("#flatpickrText").flatpickr
                        (
                            {
                                disable: jsonDateRanges

                            }
                        );
                    },
                    error: function (Result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
                //var jsonDateRangesWorks = [
                //            {
                //                from: "2017-05-01",
                //                to: "2017-05-03"
                //            },
                //            {
                //                from: "2017-05-10",
                //                to: "2017-05-12"
                //            }
                //]
            })


        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="APDH" id="ddOrganization" />
        <input type="text" id="output" style="width:600px" />
        <input type="text" id="flatpickrText" />
        <input type="button" value="Ok" id="btn" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should click on okay button, then put cursor in empty text field to see the calendar popup with excluded date ranges.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Where is the variable AjaxDataSend initiated? Looks like it's on your server side code which isn't passed to the success function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my server code, in case you need it.

```
public class AjaxDataReceive
{
    public string organizationId { get; set; }
}

public class AjaxDataSend
{
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index800(AjaxDataReceive ajaxData)
    {
        AjaxDataSend ads = new AjaxDataSend { from = "2017-05-03", 
            to = "2017-05-05" };
        AjaxDataSend ads2 = new AjaxDataSend
        {
            from = "2017-05-10",
            to = "2017-05-12"
        };

        IList<AjaxDataSend> list = new List<AjaxDataSend>();
        list.Add(ads);
        list.Add(ads2);

        return Json(new
        {
            AjaxDataSend = list
        }
                , @"application/json");
    }

    public ActionResult Index800()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sad that it doesn't work for you.  You need to change your server code, so that when you put a breakpoint in the success of the ajax call, the variable in question looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE

```html
<input class="form-`control form-control-solid flippick" placeholder="Pick event date" type="text" id="kt_datepicker_3"/>
```

Jquery CODE

```js
$(".flippick").flatpickr({
  mode: "range",
  // disable: ["2023-02-01", "2023-02-02", "2023-02-08"],
  disable: ty,
  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
  onOpen: [
    function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      $.ajax({
        "url": "<?=base_url("venue/vanueBookedDate"); ?>",
        "type": "post",
        dataType:"Json",
        "data": {
          venueId: vid,
        },
        success: function(data) {
          instance.set('disable', data);
        }
      });
    }]
  });
```

SERVER CODE PHP

```php
public function vanueBookedDate() {
  $venueID = $this->input->post('venueId');
    
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM USER_REQUEST WHERE VENUE_ID='$venueID' AND BOOKING_STATUS='CONFIRM'";
  $dataS = $this->unicon->CoreQuery($sql,'result_array');
  $dataArr = [];
  foreach ($dataS as $dataS) {
    $rangeDateS = $this->getDatesFromRange($dataS['EVENT_DATE'],$dataS['TILL_DATE']);
    
    foreach ($rangeDateS as $rangeDate) {
      $dataArr[] = $rangeDate;
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($dataArr);
}
```

Tested code